# Firefox plugin sees tags, but which tags?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

I have a simple Firefox plugin working. It gets turned on and off via menus. See the "Tools -> Classy Locator" menu items.

The plugin is going to do some reporting on the class names of elements in the HTML document. I did not think this would be so obnoxious a task.

It sees tags, but which tags? They seem to be tags in the XUL document. Lots of "menuitem" and such. And no "input" tags. I am looking at a page with a form and two text fields and there are the two input tags right there, but the plugin does not see them.

The listener function is:

```
findClassLabels : function(anEvent) {

  var doc = window.document;

  var text = "// At " + Date() + ", Page = " + doc.title + "\n";
  oStream.write(text, text.length);

  var tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

  for (var idx = 0; idx < tags.length; idx++) {
    var tag = tags[idx];
    var str = "tag: '" + tag.tagName + "' -> class: '" + tag.className + "'\n";
    oStream.write(str, str.length);
  }
  oStream.write("\nDONE\n\n", 7);
}
```

This is writing to a file, "/tmp/test.txt". That part is all working, I see the starting message and the "DONE" and not the right stuff in between.

The full project is at https://github.com/rkiddy/classy-locator-firefox-extension.git

If you clone the project, type "make", and then open the xpi file in Firefox, it will work. Hit the "Start" menu and then reload the page. You will see a bunch of output in the /tmp/test.txt file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Your comments clarified your question:

You're getting xul elements returned. Your scope is wrong. Access the tab content by doing

- `window.gBrowser.contentWindow.document.getElementsByBlassName`

  - however note that doing `contentWindow` directly on the `gBrowser` gives you the contentWindow of the **currently selected tab** you can also skip `contentWindow.document` and just do `window.gBrowser.contentDocument`.

    - `window` is the `DOMWindow` which is the browser window not the html window
- `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser.contentWindow....`

  - this gets the most recent window of windowtype navigator:browser see about window-type here:
  - you can get the window type with `aDOMWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute('windowtype')`
- go through all windows like this:

  ```
          var DOMWindows = Services.wm.getEnumerator(null);
          while (DOMWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
              var aDOMWindow = DOMWindows.getNext();
              var windowtypeOfADomWindow = aDOMWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute('windowtype');
              console.log('windowtype of this domwindow is:', windowtypeOfADomWindow)
          }
  ```

`navigator:browser` windows have a `gBrowser` and usually a `gBrowser.tabContainer` and the tabConatiner has childNodes which are tabs. So you can then go through the tabs like this:

```
var tabs = gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
    var aTab = tabs[i];
    var aTabContentWindow = aTab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow;
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp See the "Tip", that a "*" gives you all the tags. I will try what you suggest, though.

Comment: Nope. Called quaerySelectorAll("input") instead of the getElementsByClassName and got nothing. Or rather, I see nothing, for whatever reason.

Comment: do this `var collection = document.querySelectorAll('tag.class')`

Comment: Ohhhh i seee what you're doing. You're getting xul elements returned. Your scope is wrong. Access the tab content by doing `window.gBrowser.contentWindow.document.getElementsByBlassName`

Comment: if you edit the answer I can + this answer. This was it! It is absolutely amazing how many things I looked at that did not say this.